# Does PostedFile.FileName work differently in .Net 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, .net, file-upload, .net-4.0, .net-2.0

I'm working on an ASP.Net site which allows users to link documents using a UNC path.  This site is used by a customer of ours for internal processes, so all users on their domain should have access to the UNC path.

When a user wants to add a linked document, they select the file using a FileUpload control.  Previously in .Net 2.0, the control's PostedFile.FileName property returned the filename and the full UNC path.  Now we are using .Net 4.0 and it only returns the filename.

**Here's my main question:**  Does PostedFile.FileName work differently in .Net 4.0 compared to 2.0?

If not, what else could cause this problem?

Comment: It's not .NET but the internet explorer which growed up (was it IE8?).

Comment: @TimSchmelter did SO convert your answer to a comment? :P

Comment: I'm using IE9.  We have a copy of the site using .Net 2.0 and the UNC path is returned.  However, it is not returned in the copy of the site using .Net 4.0.  --so, I don't think its the browser.

Comment: I'm guessing the reason it still works on the .Net 2.0 site is due to backwards compatibility.  Although I don't know that for sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that it's not .NET but the internet explorer which growed up in security.

From [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-v-comprehensive-protection.aspx):

> Additionally, the “Include local directory path when uploading files”
>   URLAction has been set to "Disable" for the Internet Zone. This change
>   prevents leakage of potentially sensitive local file-system
>   information to the Internet. For instance, rather than submitting the
>   full path C:\users\ericlaw\documents\secret\image.png, Internet
>   Explorer 8 **will now submit only the filename image.png**.

So you could

1. Change the logic in the server-side code - It should not be dependent on the client-side file path location and should simply use the FileName property of the FileUpload control.
2. Enable the IE 8 / IE 9 option to include the local directory path for the Internet Zone on the client-side(annoy the user).

[image]

Comment: When using IE9, why does PostedFile.FileName return the path on a .Net 2.0 website, but not on a .Net 4.0 website?

Comment: Ah, okay.  I enabled the "Include local directory path when uploading files to a server" setting and it worked in the .Net 4.0 site.  It must be a combination of the browser and a change in the Framework.  Thank you for your help!