# How to insert Excel data into SQL Server database using asp.net 2012

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am working on an asp.net in which I have to all Excel data into a SQL Server table. For this I have used a file upload to upload Excel file and on button click I am inserting all data of Excel into SQL Server 2008. On the button click I have used following code:

```
protected void ImportNow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    private static string _connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database1"].ToString();
        try
        {
            if ((fileuploadExcel.FileName != ""))
            {
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileuploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName);
                string excelConnectionString;
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr);
                string tableName = "School";
                string path = fileuploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName;

                //Create connection string to Excel work book
                if (extension == ".xls")
                {
                    excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path +
                                                          ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;Persist Security Info=False";
                }
                else
                {
                    excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path +
                                                         ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False";
                }

                //Create Connection to Excel work book
                OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
                //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel            
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("truncate table " + tableName, conn);
                SqlCommand identityChange = conn.CreateCommand();
                identityChange.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT " + tableName + " ON";
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection);
                excelConnection.Open();
                OleDbDataReader dReader;
                dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                identityChange.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(_connStr);
                //Give your Destination table name
                sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
                excelConnection.Close();
                conn.Close();
                lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                lblMessage.Text = "Import into table <b>" + tableName + "</b> successful!<br />";
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                lblMessage.Text = "Please first upload (Select) excel file.";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
    }
```

When I upload an Excel file and read it then it shows error

> The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

even if there is a file having `Sheet1`. Please help me. Thanx

Comment: This is likely to be related to where the file is in relation to the code. Is this an uploaded file? Also make sure that the ASP process has sufficient permissions to see the file.

Comment: Yes this is an uploaded file.

Comment: It's likely to be a permissions problem then.

Comment: No it has read permission

Answer (score 0):

Verify whether the path of your uploaded file is valid in giving to datasource. Since the code

```
string path = fileuploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName;
```

will fail in some browsers in getting the file path, [see here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1424157.aspx?FileUpload%20Control%20PostedFile%20FileName%20is%20not%20the%20Full%20Path%20Name%20in%20Internet%20Explorer%208%20IE8%20) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403593/does-postedfile-filename-work-differently-in-net-4-0).
Try specifying the path of the file where is going to get saved as,

```
string path = @"c:\documents\files\"+ fileuploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName;
```